# nsubstitute mock method with other arguments Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mocking, nsubstitute

I have a code where I call a method e.g. MyMock.Create(true). I want to replace every call with true to false, when I am testing it in PlayMode. How to do that? I spend hours and I am just starting with NSubstitute so probably it is something quite easy...

Answer (score 0):

Inside visual studio (crtrl + f) find & replace MyMock.Create(true) with MyMock.Create(false) for the whole project. Alternatively  you could switch true with false inside the Create method like this

> bool tmp = true;
> if (param==true)
> tmp = false
> else
> tmp = true

.....

Use tmp instead of the given parameter of the Method MyMock.Create